# Manipulate consecutive sound files in java

Tags: java-audio

What i'm trying to do is making a piano song with individual sound files for the piano claps.
I did a version of it in javascript, with WebAudioAPI, using an oscillator instead of audio files. Here's a part of the code out of context:

```
var ctx = new AudioContext();
var time = ctx.currentTime;
for(...){
  osc = ctx.createOscillator();
  osc.start(time);
  time = time + 3;
  osc.stop(time);
  osc.disconnect(time);
}
```

I don't know how to stop an audio file like i did with the oscillator.
(P.S.)I only kept the part of the code that was relevant to my question, so please ignore the functionality of it.

Thank you!

Comment: Where you wrote "claps" did you mean "clips"?

Comment: @PhilFreihofner, i guess the "for the piano claps" is redundant. I was trying to say that the audio files represent the piano keys (claps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a [Clip](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html) one uses the method`stop()` to halt the playback. A subsequently called `start()` will resume playback from the same point. But one can change the playback point to a new location with either the `setFramePosition()` or `setMicrosecondPosition()` methods.

With a [SourceDataLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine.html) one can also use `start()` and `stop()` methods. But changing to a new playback point is limited and trickier. One can only move forward, and this is done by using the [skip()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#skip(long)) method of the `AudioInputStream` that is used to obtain the data being output through the `SourceDataLine`.

If the sound you are playing is only meant to be played once through, I would tend to favor using the `SourceDataLine`. If you are going to play the sound over, repeatedly, and holding the data in memory is not a burden, then `Clip` would likely be the better choice.

With `SourceDataLine` you are not limited to using `AudioInputStream` as your source signal. You can also use a custom-made oscillator or synthesizer. Converting the output of the oscillator, if it is PCM, will have to be handled to match the audio format in that case.

Comment: Thank you very much, you pointed me in the right direction. What i was searching for, the most, was Thread.sleep( ) for delaying the AudioClip.close( )

Comment: For setting up an action to occur at a given time, you might prefer using a `ScheduledExecutorService` to handle the task of executing the `close()`. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html "...can schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically." It's also possible to count frames as they are output and stop at a given frame count. The frame can be calculated in advance using the sample rate and bytes per frame. This last method is the most precise.